# How to set permission of create database to a user in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2017

I try to add a backup `.bak` in SQL Server 2017 and then I select the archive `.bak` and [I have this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsWEU.jpg).

I was looking for the error and Microsoft indicates that I must give [permission to create database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAHUn.jpg)

Comment: are you trying to restore the backup from an account having the admin privilages ?

Comment: @Anibal - Is there anything else you can add to your question to help us understand the issue better?